# Raw Query is unable to convert BLOB to string for selecting column of String[]

Tags: java, android, mysql, ormlite

I have an issue where I'm getting this error:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

I'm getting this issue with this piece of code:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults;
                rawResults = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(this)
                        .getDaoForClass(Table1.class)
                        .queryRaw("SELECT idList, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 ORDER BY idList");
List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();
```

when I'm trying to convert rawResult to results. "idList" field is String[]

I also tried to just select column with this query:

```
SELECT idList FROM Table1
```

But same error appeared.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to select frequency of objects which id's are contained inside idList field String[].

As requested, table from which I'm selecting is this:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = "type")
@Expose
@SerializedName("type")
public Type type;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "idList",  dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
@Expose
@SerializedName("idList")
public String[] idList;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = "occurredDate")
@Expose
@SerializedName("occurredDate")
public Date occurredDate;
```

Comment: Can you show the table structure also?

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan table data added.

Comment: I was looking for something which will tell me the column name and data type with size. The above structure wont reveal database table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ii idList contains ids you want to see the count then maybe the query should be like

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ID in (XXX)
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

XXX - should be the idList converted to string containing ids separated with ,
eg. 1,2,3,4,5 or '1','2','3' if the id is string